# How does Dojo differ from Jquery with Backbone or with JavascriptMVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, dojo

I'm not asking for a comparison between Dojo and Jquery, this is obvious enough, what I'm asking is how does Dojo compare to Jquery AND an mvc like Backbone (Backbone in particular) or JavascriptMVC? Does Dojo itself already cover what Backbone does? does Backbone do more? Also, can I use Backbone and Underscore with Dojo and would that be seamless?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say Dojo is like Jquery plus a widgeting system, a widget library and a build system.

see Phillip's comment below for information on MVC in dojo

Backbone uses jquery. it is possible to use jquery and dojo together but it's always preferable to stick with one or the other if you can.

Comment: Dojo does indeed have MVC ability.  There is an entire tutorial on it's MVC application on the Dojo site:  http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/data_modeling/